# Library not found when using the arduino-cli command (although working with the Arduino IDE)

Tags: library, compile, compilation-errors, arduino-cli

I have a sketch which I can upload without problem with the Arduino IDE. I installed the arduino-cli  Version: 0.28.0 Commit: 06fb1909 Date: 2022-10-18T15:53:04Z. I want to compile and upload a code on an arduino uno and use the command line

```
arduino-cli compile --fqbn arduino:avr:uno mysketch.ino
```

but get the following error:

```
/path/to/mysketch.ino:44:10: fatal error: LiquidCrystal.h: No such file or directory
 #include <LiquidCrystal.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.



Used platform Version Path
arduino:avr   1.8.5   /Users/user/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.5

Error during build: exit status 1
```

how could I proceed to debug?

Comment: `/path/to/mysketch.ino` looks like an invalid path

Comment: @jsotola. Thank you for your comment. It is indeed not the real path. I edited it for the question. But it is the path where the `.ino` file is

Comment: `how to debug?` ... if your OS is Windows ... download process monitor from Microsoft ... use it to figure out where the program is looking for the file ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LiquidCrystal library is bundles with Arduino IDE 1 so it is not installed in your sketchbook folder's `libraries` folder so CLI can't find it.

Install the library with Arduino CLI or simply copy it from Arduino IDE 1 installation folder into `libraries` folder of your sketchbook.

Comment: many thanks for your answer @Juraj. what would be the command to install it with the Arduino CLI?

Comment: @ecjb you work with CLI and you don't know the commands? https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/latest/commands/arduino-cli_lib_install/

Comment: The command is: **`arduino-cli lib install LiquidCrystal`** for future visitors' convenience.